# VSShellStub2.exe - System Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vsix, vsx, visual-studio-package

What are the prerequisites to be installed in a Target machine for running  the application developed using  Microsoft Visual studio Isolated Shell 2013.

In a fresh Win7 SP1 64bit machine, I have installed Microsoft Visual studio Isolated Shell 2013 Redistributable package.

But i got an error when starting the application

> ### VSShellStub2.exe - System Error
>
> The program can't start because MSVCR120D.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the
>   program to fix this problem.

Do i need to install any other application to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found out the issue,

Visual studio Isolated Shell Redistributable package is not including debug version for c(Msvcr120d.dll) and C++(Msvcp120d.dll ) run time. So application should be build in release mode to make it working in a fresh system with VS Isolated Shell Redistributable package

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn448963(v=vs.85).aspx